# KnockoutJS Live Validation Localization

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm attempting to localize the KnockoutJS validation plugin, but I need to be able to switch between languages on the fly. There's an [issue open on the plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/issues/158) but it's over 2 years old (and still open).

What I'm simply trying to do is switch the languages of the validation messages after everything is loaded.  Here's an example (can be seen on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kikketer/S6j2q/)

```
<input data-bind='value: phone' />
<div data-bind="text: phone"></div>
<button type='button' data-bind="click: v">Validate</button>
<button type='button' data-bind='click: switchLanguage'>Switch Language</button>
```

With the following JS:

```
ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true
});
// If I localize right away, things work
ko.validation.localize({required: '**Required'});

var InterviewTwo = function() {
    // Standard "required" validator
    this.phone = ko.observable().extend({required: true});

    // Group all of the validators
    this.errors = ko.validation.group(this);

    // Validation function
    this.v = function() {
        this.errors.showAllMessages();
    };

    // Switching languages after or before the validation
    this.switchLanguage = function() {
        // If I localize later, nothing is changed.
        ko.validation.localize({required: 'eh... sorta?'});
        ko.validation.registerExtenders();
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new InterviewTwo());
```

I noticed in the knockout code, the getter method for the error always returns the first localization error string.  How do I "reinitialize" the error strings?

From KnockoutJS line 736:

```
var errorMsgAccessor = function () {
    if (!config.messagesOnModified || isModified) {
        return isValid ? null : obsv.error; <<<< obsv.error is always the first error message
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is the problem. It seems it is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/8MWGR/ . Click on Validate you see "This field is required." then type something in to remove the message. Then click on switch language and if you delete the text you will see "eh... sorta?"

Comment: Good call, that works.  I guess what I'm trying to do is either programmatically clear the errors when I switch languages (then revalidate) or switch the error string when the "Switch Languages" button is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code updates the localization, but the new messages will work only on the next update.

Replace switchLanguage with this:

```
this.switchLanguage = function() {
    // If I localize later, nothing is changed.
    ko.validation.localize({required: 'eh... sorta?'});
    for (var prop in this)
        if (ko.isObservable(this[prop]) && typeof(this[prop].valueHasMutated) === 'function')
            this[prop].valueHasMutated();        
};
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8MWGR/2/)**

Comment: You saved my life, I really baffled that this answer has no so much upvote, it should be upvoted as rocket sky.